# Can a plastic degrading bacteria science fair project be recreated in a school lab?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

i am just looking for a science fair project and am fascinated by this topic. i was wondering if a project concerning the isolation of plastic degrading bacteria could be done in a school lab. I am in grade 10. Anything helps!

Comment: This mostly depends on the equipment available in the school lab & as well as time and resources available. If you can add a few more details about either the equipment present in your school, it'd be easier to say what would be possible. The other way around if you describe in more detail what you'd like to do, it's easier to say what would be needed exactly.

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the materials needed since this is just the beginning stages of finding a project. From what I've researched, the main objective would be to isolate bacteria from soils, to test these isolates for ability to degrade different types of plastic and to identify these microbes. We have until December 14 to finish experimentation and would have help from a lab technician. Do you know if this type of project would be possible and what we should inform our lab technician with in order to help us? Thanks!

Comment: You should speak with your lab technician asap - he/she will know much better what exactly can be done in the lab and will need to done. Note that 2 months is a rather short timeframe to do an experimental project, esp. since growing isolated bacterial strains is not always straightforward